# Tab-Key blocks Circumflex (^)

Tags: qt

i have a little Application where i can choose items by pressing ^, 1, 2, ...

The problem is, when i press tab the ^-key (Qt::Key_AsciiCircum) doesn't work anymore until i press the tab-key again. Anyway the numbers are still working and are handled in the same keyPressEvent(...) !

I tried to also handle the tab-key but it seems it doesn't even reach my event-handler (cout << event->key() doesn't print anything).

I just found out that the left/right arrows also don't work. Probably another widget catches those keys? But if thats the case, how can i find it?

thx, eL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the most likely explanation: **Tab** usually means *go to next widget*. If you've got two widgets tab might be alternating between them (try adding a text box?).

Look into how you can 'change' the tab order or somehow disable it to fix that.

Comment: Phew - long time ago.
But i finally managed it by connecting the focusChanged-Signal to a Slot and printed out some informations about the Widget and i could track down a QLineEdit. Though i can't imagine why only circumflex was blocked.